# Login Error in Firebase for Nativescript

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, nativescript

Hi i try to instance my password login in nativescript but send me this error:

```
JS: error con login por email Logging in the user failed. com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ {
JS:   "error":{
JS:     "code": 400,
JS:     "message": "USER_NOT_FOUND",
JS:     "errors": [
JS:       {
JS:         "message": "USER_NOT_FOUND",
JS:         "domain": "global",
JS:         "reason": "invalid"
JS:       }
JS:     ]
JS:   }
JS: } ]
```

here is my code:

```
constructor() {
      firebase.login({
        type: firebase.LoginType.PASSWORD,
        passwordOptions: {
         email: 'test@test.com',
         password: 'test@test.com'
       }


      }).then((user)=>{
        console.dir(user);
      }, (error)=>{
        console.log("error con login por email "+ error);
      }

      )
    }
```

can you help me to find why gives me that error?
when I login anonymous doesn't have errors

Comment: It's exactly what the error says: "No user found." Are you sure such a user exists? Check the Firebase Console > Authentication to see if the user exists.

Comment: id: test@test.com uid: 3u7jZZphi9fGjpbBSwBxF5Li6DE2
here is the user, i created before

Comment: Did you correctly initialise Firebase? Screenshot of your auth (just to double-check.)?

Comment: yes, as i said, i can create anonymous users whit no problems

Comment: Are you testing on an emulator or real device? This might not work on emulator https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/463

Comment: real device, not emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if you don't forget to enable email-password login in your firebase instance.

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/AUTHENTICATION.md#email-password-login